# Creating New Javascript Object With Variable Arguments

Tags: javascript

I have class `Foo`, and want to make a function `FooPrime` which is equivalent to call `new Foo()` with the arguments passed to `FooPrime`;

In other words, if I do:

```
FooPrime(1, 2, 3);
```

it should be the same as calling to:

```
new Foo(1, 2, 3)
```

Normally I'd use `call` or `apply` for this sort of thing, and I can get almost the same effect using apply:

```
var FooPrime = function() {
    return Foo.apply({}, arguments);
}
```

However:

```
Foo.apply({}, [1, 2, 3]);
```

is not exactly the same as calling:

```
new Foo(1, 2, 3)
```

so my question is, is there any way to make a function which does *exactly* the same thing as `new`, with any number of arguments?

Comment: `new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Foo, [null].concat(argsArray)))();` (borrowed from [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=let%20a%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%0Aconst%20f%20%3D%20function(a%2Cb%2Cc)%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20new%20f(...a)%3B%0A%0A))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5 you can polyfill [[[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) with something like this:

```
function isObject(o) {
  return Object(o) === o;
}
function construct(F, args) {
  var obj = isObject(F.prototype) ? Object.create(Foo.prototype) : {},
      res = Function.prototype.apply.call(F, obj, args);
  return isObject(res) ? res : obj;
}
var FooPrime = function() {
  return construct(Foo, arguments);
}
```

ECMAScript 6 provides the simpler and more reliable [`Reflect.construct`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.construct)

```
var FooPrime = function() {
  return Reflect.construct(Foo, arguments);
}
```

Or you can also use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which has more browser support than `Reflect`.

```
var FooPrime = function() {
  return new Foo(...arguments);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, except unfortunately it doesn't work with es6 classes, ie. `class Foo` (it gives `TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'`).  By any chance is there an equivalent for an es6 class (but without the use of Reflect, since Chrome doesn't currently support it)?

Comment: @machineghost You can use the spread operator: `new Foo(...arguments)`